# Compilation aborted when trying to create object type on Oracle live SQL

Tags: sql, oracle, plsql

I am running the following code on Oracle live SQL but I am getting compilation aborted error and I can't figure out what's casing the issue. Any ideas?

```
CREATE TYPE AppointmentType AS OBJECT (
    appointment# NUMBER,
    date DATE,
    time NUMBER,
    appointmentType VARCHAR2(50),
    levelOfInterest NUMBER,
    offerMade NUMBER,
    MEMBER FUNCTION isOfferMade RETURN BOOLEAN
);

CREATE TYPE BODY AppointmentType AS
    MEMBER FUNCTION isOfferMade RETURN BOOLEAN IS
    BEGIN
        RETURN offerMade > 0;
    END isOfferMade;
END;
```

`

I could not find anything wrong with the code.

Comment: DATE is a reserved word.  Why do you have a separate "time" field?  DATE data type supports date/time to seconds resolution.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Column name can't be `date`, it is reserved for datatype with the same name (as OldProgrammer already commented). Another *error* is `appointmentType`; if you leave that name, Oracle raises

> PLS-00488: 'SELF.APPOINTMENTTYPE' must be a type

Once fixed:

```
SQL> CREATE OR REPLACE TYPE AppointmentType AS OBJECT (
  2      appointment#      NUMBER,
  3      c_date            DATE,
  4      time              NUMBER,
  5      c_appointmentType VARCHAR2(50),
  6      levelOfInterest   NUMBER,
  7      offerMade         NUMBER,
  8      MEMBER FUNCTION isOfferMade RETURN BOOLEAN
  9  );
 10  /

Type created.

SQL> CREATE OR REPLACE TYPE BODY AppointmentType AS
  2      MEMBER FUNCTION isOfferMade RETURN BOOLEAN IS
  3      BEGIN
  4          RETURN offerMade > 0;
  5      END isOfferMade;
  6  END;
  7  /

Type body created.

SQL>
```